# Node js error when trying the POST request

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I don't understand why I am getting "cannot post" error. Please help.

```
const app = express();

//Adding Body Parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.json({
        status: "200"
    })
})

app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    var city = req.body.city;
    res.status(200).json({stat: city})
})
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. can you post the entire error message as well? that might be useful in finding out the issue

Comment: This is the error => Cannot POST /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you start app with `app.listen(port)` (`port` is your port).

I use your code (add `app.listen(port)`) and post ok.

This is my code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
//Adding Body Parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.json({
        status: "200"
    })
})

app.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    var city = req.body.city || '1';
    res.status(200).json({stat: city})
})

app.listen(4567)
```

I use Insomnia and this is my result:
[image]

Comment: My get request is working fine. The only issue is in POST request

Comment: @user17315 can you also check if doing a POST for any other sample Node app works? I might be wrong but this could be a firewall issue

Comment: Let me try again with my other script

Comment: All other codes are working fine. No firewall issue. Can you share the whole code that you ran on Insomnia

Comment: @user17315,  @HongarC mentioned that he used your code as-is and it worked. The only difference I see between your code and his is the last line `app.listen(4567)`

Comment: The issue in  my code was the Port number. I had initially set it to 4000 which didn't seem to work until I switched to port 4567. Thanks for the help Hongarc and @raghav710

Answer (score 0):

It might be the problem with the port. Changing the port number might help.